# Why is this table not normalized?

Tags: sql, normalization

I am taking a database course and I am studying table normalization.

[image]

Could anyone explain to me, why the second table in the first row on the right not normalized?

Comment: The top-left table doesn't seem to be a very good design either.

Comment: Right now unless you intend to only give 1 grade you would have to add the user again if he received multiple grades since you cant set multiple grades in the same column/row

Comment: I would suggest posting database-only question to [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/), stackoverflow isn't the right place to ask this

Answer (score 2):

It is not normalized because
For a student who has signed for more than one course, the entries in the table will be:
23 Jake Smith CS101 B+
23 Jake Smith B102 C+
**Clearly the data is being repeated(redundant data)**. It is leading to **anomalies(insert, update, delete anomalies)**. 
**Ex:**
When you have to change the name of a Student say Jake Smith, you have to modify all of the rows,this is called an update anomalie.

Normalization is used to avoid these kind of anomalies and redundant data storage.

The table on the right hand side in the second row handles this situation in a better way, as it stores `id, name and DOB` in a separate table, the edits can be made easily using `id` attribute on a single row.

There are several normal forms like 1NF, 2NF, 3NF etc. Each normal form has some constraints associated with it. Each Higher form being stricter than the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is table for students grades. It is not normalized because it contains students names directly, instead of references to students records.

It's better not to include `student_name` into this table, but store all students data in separate `students` table and reference it by  `student_id` foreign key (something like first table in second row except the ids.).

Answer (score 0):

It's not normalised because neither `id` nor `student_name` is the key (both have duplicates) so the key must be one of those (probably `id`) together with the course code. The other one (`name`) then doesn't depend on that key, but just on `id`.

The simple rule for 3NF is that every non-key column must depend on "the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key" - to which we all solemnly intone "so help me Codd"!

The higher normal forms deal with dependencies inside the parts of a key.

Answer (score -1):

Because in your first right table you have twice values

> 23 - j.smith

that is repeated and do not adhere to Codd 1 normal form